# App terminated unexpectedly on iPhone device, but working fine on Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

The application that developing is running fine on Xcode simulator, but when I am testing it on real device is terminated. Below is what my phone's console prints out when app is terminated.

```
Nov 22 00:51:09 iPhone ReportCrash[3862] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process CoL[3860]
��Nov 22 00:51:09 iPhone ReportCrash[3862] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
��Nov 22 00:51:09 iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:pan.ConquestOfLancaster[0xd857][3860]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:pan.ConquestOfLancaster[0xd857]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
��Nov 22 00:51:09 iPhone backboardd[52] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:pan.ConquestOfLancaster[0xd857]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
��Nov 22 00:51:09 iPhone ReportCrash[3862] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/CoL_2012-11-22-005109_iPhone.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
��Nov 22 00:51:09 iPhone awdd[3863] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
```

Basically, the problem occurs when I am firing a NSTimer (countdown) and reach '1'. Freeze for a while and then terminated.

Here is the method where timer initialised:

```
- (void)MapMenu:(MapMenu *)menu didSelectButton:(NSInteger)index{

    if (index == 0) {
        if (self.owner == nil && distance < 10) {
            CountDownTimer* countDown = [[CountDownTimer alloc]init];
            [countDown startTimerOn:parentView];
            [self performSelector:@selector(attackTo:attacker:) withObject:nil afterDelay:20.0];
        }
        else if (self.owner == @"Player_1")
            NSLog(@"You have already occupy this building with name, %@", self.title);
    }
}

- (void) attackTo: (BuildingViewController*) selectedBuilding attacker: (NSString*) attacker{

    self.owner = @"Player_1";
    NSLog(@"Building has a new owner with name, %@", self.owner);
}
```

Does anyone has a clue for this. Really ... lost!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since it says, "Formulating crash report," maybe that would help.

Comment: Sorry @PhillipMills, didn't get your point. :(

Comment: There is a crash report being created, you should look at it. Use the Xcode organizer and check the crash reports on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the source of the crash, but you do have a problem right here:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(attackTo:attacker:) withObject:nil afterDelay:20.0];
```

Basically, the fact that selector call has two `:` means that it is expecting two arguments.  If you use the method `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, you can only use it with a method that has one argument.

For example,

```
[self performSelector:@selector(doSomething:) withObject:object afterDelay:20.0f]
```

is equivalent to

```
[self doSomething:object]
```

and it will be performed after about 20 seconds.

In this case, you have a mismatch because your `@selector` takes *two* arguments, so you can not use it with that particular `performSelector` method.

While there is a `performSelector:withObject:withObject` method that takes two arguments, it does not have a `delay` argument.  You might need to use `NSInvocation` instead, or change the `attackTo:attacker:` so that it uses a single argument (for example, an NSDictionary).

Answer (score 0):

I see your using a class called CountDownTimer. Is this a subclass of NSTimer? If so, you should read the subclassing notes in the NSTimer class reference.
[NSTimer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Basically, it says don't do it. Actually no not even basically, it says don't do it.

While your reading the class reference take a look at how to implement a callback after n seconds. Personally, I like `+ scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`

Comment: Hello @atreat. No my CountDownTimer is subclass of UIView. There I am just calling a method 20 times in order to update timer on screen using scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval method. I have missed a point?

Comment: hmmm. By your class name I assumed differently. Have you looked at the crash report in your file  /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/CoL_2012-11-22-005109_iPhone.plist?